# Python script runs in rc.local, but won't save file, Works from command line

Tags: python, boot

I have a python script that saves values from a MPU6050 sensor to a csv, and then zips the file.  When I run it from Thonny or direct from the command line, it works.  When I run from rc.local at startup it shows up as running in 'Task Manager' but the files do not save.

My rc.local:

```
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

sudo python /home/pi/Code/Prospectus/RecordAcceleration.py &

exit 0
```

My python script named RecordAcceleration.py stored in /home/pi/Code/Prospectus/:

```
#This is for Sensor Number
SeNum = 4

import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import mpu6050 as mp
import time
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
import os
path = '/'

sensor = mp.mpu6050(0x68)

start = time.time()

j = 1

GB = 2

if len(os.listdir('/media/pi')) ==0:
    path = '/home/pi/AccelData'
else:
    if not os.path.isdir('/media/pi/' + os.listdir('/media/pi')[0] +'/AccelData'):
        os.mkdir('/media/pi/' + os.listdir('/media/pi')[0] +'/AccelData')
    path = '/media/pi/' + os.listdir('/media/pi')[0] +'/AccelData/'

while GB > 1:
    Results = []
    FileStart = time.time()
    for i in range(60000):
        try:
            gx, gy, gz = sensor.get_accel_data(True)
        except:
            del sensor
            time.sleep(0.01)
            sensor = mp.mpu6050(0x68)
            gx, gy, gz = sensor.get_accel_data(True)
        #tx, ty, tz = sensor.get_gyro_data()
        Results.append([time.strftime('%y%m%d-%H%M%S.')+str(int((time.time()-int(time.time()))*10000%10000)).zfill(4), gx, gy, gz,SeNum])
        time.sleep(0.00001)

    Results = np.matrix(Results)

    NextFileName = '60kPoints-'+time.strftime('%y%m%d-%H%M')+'-s'+str(SeNum)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=Results)
    df.to_csv(NextFileName+'.csv', sep=',', header=False, float_format='%.5f')
    
    print(j, (time.time()-start) / 60.0, NextFileName)
    j+=1

    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(path + NextFileName+'.zip', 'w')
    zip_file.write(NextFileName+'.csv', compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zip_file.close()
    
    os.remove(NextFileName+'.csv')
    
    st = os.statvfs(path)
    bytes_avail = (st.f_bavail * st.f_frsize)
    GB = bytes_avail / 1024 / 1024 / 1024
```

Comment: Are you sure the path + name is always valid? You seem to be missing a '/' when there's no mounted drive in `/media/pi` (which most likely is the case when you're using rc.local (personally I wouldn't use rc.local anyway... and no need for sudo in rc.local)

Comment: @Dirk, the missing '/' at the end of the path if no drive was mounted was the issue.  The script starts running before the drive is mounted, so that it always runs with no external.  That then causes it to use the '/home/pi' directory written wrong.  I added a time.sleep(10) after the imports, and now the drive is always mounted when I get to that point, and the code is fixed should a drive not be mounted.  Appreciate the help.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`rc.local` has been *deprecated* for some time - [here's one description explaining its current state](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471871/286615). You shouldn't use `rc.local` because it's not supported any longer.

There are two common alternatives for running your script at startup:

1, `cron` with the `@reboot` invocation,
2. create a "unit file" to run under `systemd`

As a general comparison between the two options, `cron` is simpler, while `systemd` gives you more control once you've *"done your homework"*

#### `cron`:

Setting up a `cron` job to run at startup is generally straightforward. Open your `crontab` for editing:

```bsh
$ crontab -e
```

This opens your `crontab` file in your default editor.

Then add your "job(s)" - for example, to run a Python script named `HelloWorld.py` located in pi's home directory at start/boot time requires a single line be added to your `crontab`:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/HelloWorld.py
```

This is all that's needed for a very simple `cron` job, but complications arise in many *real-world* applications. I feel that using `cron` successfully requires an understanding of its limitations - [I've tried to summarize those here](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/MyCrontabDoesntWork.md) with solutions that will often overcome these limitations.

I noted that your `rc.local` command calls your Python script using `sudo` - suggesting that it must be run with `root` privileges. If that's the case, you should use the `root crontab` instead of using `sudo` in your `pi user crontab`. You may get away with using `sudo` in a `pi` user `crontab` in Raspberry Pi (due to how user `pi` is configured), but it won't work properly on most other Unix/Linux systems. Otherwise, using the `root crontab` is virtually identical to using a user `crontab`:

```bsh
$ sudo crontab -e
```

There are [many Q&A here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=cron) on using `cron` to schedule jobs - [I have answered a few](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A83790+cron) myself.

#### `systemd`:

Scheduling a job to run at start/boot time may also be accomplished using what is called a `systemd unit` file. `systemd` is considered by some to be a better solution in many cases because it does not have some of `cron`'s limitations. Many would say creating the `unit` file is more difficult than creating a `cron` job, but like most new tasks, a little experience will make things considerably easier over time.

I won't try to walk through creation of a `unit` file, but there are many [tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=linux+create+systemd+unit+file&atb=v278-1&ia=web) available online. There's a [brief overview of a `unit` file creation here](https://serverfault.com/a/951289/515728) that will be useful for RPi users (as RPi is a Debian derivative). There are also [numerous Q&A here on RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A79866+systemd+unit) that may be useful.

Comment: I will try to set it up with a cron job and see if it is more stable.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It was a missing '/' in path if no drive is mounted.  The drive does not mount until after the script is already running, so it tries to use the /home/pi location, but I had a mistake there.  When I run it after boot, it works fine because the drive is mounted.  I added a time.sleep(10) after the imports, and that delay is sufficient for the drives to mount.